# Totally erroneous answer accepted

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

In this post : 
[if/then/else statements in Windows batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845409/if-then-else-statements-in-windows-batch)

the accepted answer is fundamentally erroneous. I can't comment on the answer, nor can I contact the user who posted it.

Should I modify it? I didn't do it since the edit hint clearly specifies that you should respect the author. So what can I do?

Comment: Leave a comment, vote down the answer, and/or post a better answer. *Don't* modify the other answer.

Comment: Well, without making us read the answer and hope we all understand it since not everyone here participates in all the same tags, can you explain *what about it* you find so erroneous?

Comment: Seeing as the answerer has 12.6k rep with silver `batch` and `batch-file` tags, are you certain his post is incorrect? In any case, you are not far off the 50-point mark for commenting; earn those extra points with other good answers and come back to this post if you feel strongly about it.

Comment: I guess even the best of us can make mistakes... I am certain there is a mistake in the answer. and I see from the comments that I am not the only one to think so.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In general, if you see another answer which is wrong, according to you, you can:

- **Downvote it**. *You can downvote as soon as you have 125 of [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation).*
- **Leave a comment under the answer, explaining what is wrong about it according to you**. The author will be notified of your comment. *You can comment the other answer with 50 of reputation.*
- As a last resort, **if the answer is actually harmful** (for example: unexpected loss of data, virus, phishing,...), and that's your only way to warn about it, you can **flag it** for moderator attention, and explain the issue. *(Reputation needed: 15)*

But in general, keep in mind that what is "accepted" is decided only by the one who asked the question. There are numerous cases of questions with popular answers, but the asker chose something else, most likely because it *answered their own need*. And that's ok like this. Votes are there to determine the better answers according to the community, in most cases.

Comment: we have a decline reason on our flags, "Flags should not be used to point out technical inaccuracies, or generally wrong answers."  If the answer was just wrong, flagging it would result in a declination.  It's important for people get understand that.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - I meant harmful answers only. I thought the bit about the sharks and the abyss was clear. For example, a script which will erase most of the content of a drive, if used, while it's supposed to do something else. Or a link to a malicious or phishing website. If someone sees it, but can't edit it out, I think it's a good (though rare) case to call for a moderator.

Comment: *"decline reason on our flags". Kids and their new toys, grmbl, didn't have that in my time, grmbl grmbl*

Comment: @Gnoupi It doesn't matter how wrong it is - mods will decline such a flag. 20k users have the ability to vote to delete 'dangerously wrong' answers.

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Maybe from the SO perspective. But there are not that many 20k users on the other sites. But besides, I don't see which mods would decline a flag saying that an answer has to potential to be misleading and/or dangerous. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @Gnoupi It's possible that mods may delete such a flagged post on a low-volume site with a dearth of 20ks, but as for you not being able to see what mods would decline such flags in general - a mod just told you they will. And I can verify that they do, in fact, decline such flags. (a couple of my 14 declined flags were exactly such declines, before I knew the difference, and there have been other posts here that have made it clear flagging is *not* for inaccuracies)

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Like I said, maybe on SO the perspective is different, because of the important volume. On SuperUser, those flags were (and would be today) dealt with by the moderator.

Comment: I'm surprised it would happen on SU, but I don't doubt your word on that at all. Perhaps you could edit your answer to indicate that such flags risk being declined, except on less busy sites, and that they are always declined on SO?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - Ok, maybe my point wasn't clear enough. I removed the metaphor and other fluff from the answer. I really only mean such extreme cases.

Comment: @AndrewBarber on [su] if I know that the answer is egregiously bad, then I do mark the flags as helpful. If I'm on the fence, I tend to leave it for few hours and defer it to the other mods. Once I realize that there's no action done, I'll decline the flag with the "Flags should not be used to point out technical inaccuracies" message